# How to print an instance of a parent class in base class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am able to print the name of Class Student when I inherit the class into Sports and define the values in the init method.
but I am not able to figure out how to print the name given when Student class is created without defining the name in Sports class,

When I comment out the `Student.__init__(self, 1, "name1", "addr1", 123456789, "std2@gmail.com", 1, 2021, "english")`
and define the values when the object is created, i want to print out these values.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub):
        self.sid = sid
        self.name = name
        self.addr = addr
        self.phno = phno
        self.mailid = mailid
        self.sec = sec
        self.year = year
        self.sub = sub

    def printStudent(self):
        print("name",self.name,"sid",self.sid,"sec",self.sec,"year",self.year,"sub",
              self.sub, "address",self.addr,"mailid",self.mailid,"phno",self.phno)


class Sports(Student):
    def __init__(self, nofsports, nofawards):
        Student.__init__(self, 1, "name1", "addr1", 123456789, "std2@gmail.com", 1, 2021,
                         "english")
        self.nofsports = nofsports
        self.nofawards = nofawards

    def printSports(self):
        print("name", self.name)


s1 = Student(2,"name2","addr2",1221232332,"std1@gmail.com",1,2020,"math")

s2 = Sports(2, 2)
s2.printSports()
```

When I comment out the `Student.__init__(self, 1, "name1", "addr1", 123456789, "std2@gmail.com", 1, 2021, "english")`
and define the values when the object is created, I want to print out those values.

BTW, I am learning inheritance and new to python, and I could not understand why python is not able to print the instance of `Student` class as I have inherited it, maybe because it is not class attribute? Please let me know...

Comment: I think you just want to print out s2.printStudent() right? On a side note, you should check out super for your __init__ inheritence and f-expressions for your printing.

Comment: I want to print the "self.name" from "printSports()" method without calling the "Student.__init..." in Sports class as the class is inherited, and print the name using the s2.printSports().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a subclass `__init__` method takes all the parameters of its superclass, plus any additional parameters the subclass needs. Then it can pass the common parameters to the superclass's `__init__` method.

```
class Sports(Student):
    def __init__(self, sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub, nofsports, nofawards):
        super().__init__(sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub)
        self.nofsports = nofsports
        self.nofawards = nofawards

    def printSports(self):
        print("name", self.name)

s2 = Sports(1, "name1", "addr1", 123456789, "std2@gmail.com", 1, 2021, "english", 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood now clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Student():

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            print("creating new object")
            cls._instance = super(Student, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub):
        self.sid = sid
        self.name = name
        self.addr = addr
        self.phno = phno
        self.mailid = mailid
        self.sec = sec
        self.year = year
        self.sub = sub

    def printStudent(self):
        print("name",self.name,"sid",self.sid,"sec",self.sec,"year",self.year,"sub",
              self.sub, "address",self.addr,"mailid",self.mailid,"phno",self.phno)


class Sports(Student):
    def __init__(self, nofsports, nofawards, sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub):
        super().__init__(sid, name, addr, phno, mailid, sec, year, sub)
        self.nofsports = nofsports
        self.nofawards = nofawards

    def printSports(self):
        print("name", self.name)


s2 = Sports(2,2,2,"name2","addr2",1221232332,"std1@gmail.com",1,2020,"math")
s2.printSports()
s3 = Sports(2,2,2,"name3","addr3",56516516,"std3@gmail.com",1,2020,"phy")
s3.printStudent()
s2.printStudent()
```

**

```
creating new object
name name2
name name3 sid 2 sec 1 year 2020 sub phy address addr3 mailid std3@gmail.com phno 56516516
name name3 sid 2 sec 1 year 2020 sub phy address addr3 mailid std3@gmail.com phno 56516516
```

**

Hope that will help you to understand more, Create the object of the child class instead of creating the object of the base class. Also, the base class is made a singleton class so that only one object exists